# Hive JDBC Kerberose Authentication Error: GSS initiate failed

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to Hive through JDBC using the following connection string:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")

hiveConString = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@HADOOP.LOCALDOMAIN"
```

Though I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@HADOOP.LOCALDOMAIN:GSS initiate failed
```

I already checked the hive-site.xml to ensure that kerbersoe authentication is followed. The XML file includes:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal</name>
   <value>hive/_HOST@HADOOP.LOCALDOMAIN</value>
</property>
```

I have also made sure that all of the required Maven repositories are included.

Also, I am running the code on a VM using Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using a VM with kerberos authentication and your authentication has not expired you will need to specify the following VM arguments when running your java code:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.debug=true 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf="/etc/krb5.conf"
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

Comment: `java -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Djava.security.krb5.conf="/etc/krb5.conf" -jar <JAR_FILE>` 
I used the above command but still, it was failing with the exception **GSS initiate failed**

Comment: It works for me by adding `-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ranger and connect with hive plugin and facing GSS initiate Failed error then use username@realmname like maroof@abc.com and password of maroof@abc.com and then try the jdbc connection

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;principal=hive/_HOST@HADOOP.LOCALDOMAIN
```

you will connect without any error.